# Getting a list from a different module using a string?

Tags: python, eclipse

I'm trying to get strings randomly from a list, then use the string that comes out of it to find a list of the same name as the string from a different module to determine what the enemies stats are in a combat instance.

For example, I have the level 1 Enemy list which might be something like:

```
Lv1MonsterList = ["goblinlv1", "banditLv1", "elementalLv1"]
```

I have a variable set to randomly pick one from that list:

```
trueMonster = random.choice(Lv1MonsterList)
```

Then in another module (`globalvarDB`) I have a list for each string in the first list with the stats of the enemy in. For example:

```
goblinLv1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
banditLv1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
elementalLv1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

So I want to use the `trueMonster`'s value to get all the information from the corresponding table in the other module. Is this possible?

Comment: Good news! You don't need to use strings at all - you can just insert the stat values directly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You will need to organise your file structure very simply.

Let's name your 'enemy list' file `enemylist.py`. Then you want to place your `enemylist.py` in the same directory as `globalvarDB`:

```
..
--> enemylist.py
--> globalvarDB.py
```

With this in place, you can now do the following in `enemylist.py`:

```
from globalvarDB import goblinLv1, banditLv1, elementalLv1

Lv1MonsterList = [goblinlv1, banditLv1, elementalLv1]
trueMonster = random.choice(Lv1MonsterList)
```

Now `goblinlv1`, for example, will resolve to `[1,2,3,4,5]` when you call it. If `trueMonster` is now set to `goblinlv1`, then it will also resolve to `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Note that you're no longer dealing with *strings* here, you're directly referring to the list you want (this is good practice, as it avoids a layer of obfuscation).

---

The essential technique is exactly the same - a simple `import` statement will resolve everything - but there are other ways to organise your file structure as well, such as

- Placing `globalvarDB` on your `PYTHONPATH`, so Python can access it anywhere on your system.
- Placing it in its own folder (say `utils`) with a blank `__init__.py` file declared inside the root directory, so you have something like

  ```
  ..
  --> enemylist.py
  --> utils
      --> globalvarDB.py
      --> __init__.py
  ```

  in which case you want to do `from utils.globalvar import ...` instead in your `enemylist.py`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! this is really helpful to know! P.S: It worked perfectly!